# KendoUI version of JQUERY animated side navigation

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-mobile

I am fond of the type of side navigation menu that is common in mobile apps. An example is: http://www.jqueryscript.net/menu/jQuery-Animated-Side-Navigation-Menu-Plugin-Sidebar.html

Which works also for web pages. However, the vast majority of my page is in KendoUI, and I don't want to load another framework just for that.

Is there a combination of tricks with Kendo (draw control for example) that I could use to get the same effect?

---

Alternatively, I am all wet. I just want a quick way to have a "pop-up" of settings that are only occasionally used, and most of the time save the screen real-estate. So maybe just a button and a pop-up window is the correct approach?

Any advice?

Comment: i had same problem, and as solution i created own dock panel https://github.com/onitecsoft/smarti.dock.js

Comment: JsBin demo did not work for me with Chrome 46.0.2490.86 m, desktop. Anyway I think I once saw an article how to do this with Kendo, which was my question.

Comment: weird, i am using same browser and it works for me, there is rounded button, which hide panel when clicked